# Using find -exec how to print name of file in front of each line?

Tags: awk, find, regular-expression, cat, exec

Similar to, but beyond:

```
find . -iname "somepatter*txt" -print -exec cat {} \;
```

How might the file name from each file be printed in front of each line with the results from find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -iname "somepattern*txt" -exec grep -H '' {} \+
```

Kind of an abuse of `grep`, but it works. Has the bonus of spawning the minimal available processes. This assumes you don't want a single line with the filename before each file.

Comment: Why `-H` ? The question never mentioned symbolic links.

Comment: @DarkHeart   "-H, --with-filename Print  the  file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search." Probably for the edge case of only one file being passed to `grep`.

Comment: @muru - ah ok - on my server `-H` is something different.

Comment: @DarkHeart probably not GNU grep.

Answer (score 1):

Inelegant approach:

```
find . -iname "somepattern*txt" -exec awk -v a={} '{ print a " " $0 }' {} \;
```

Comment: Less inelegant `-exec awk '{print FILENAME " " $0}' {} +`.

Comment: This is what I'd worked on before posting the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can't find be skipped altogether? `awk '{ print "\""FILENAME"\","$0 }' *.csv`